# Ruby - Match And Replace Only Specific Characters In Email

Tags: regex, ruby, pattern-matching, match

I have an email address as `xyz_abc@gmail.com` which I want to replace as `xy****@gmail.com`.
The criteria for the same is as below:

1. Convert all the characters to * before @ symbol in email.
2. Replace characters after leaving first 2 characters up to @ symbol.

For the same I have written logic as below:

```rb
"xyz_abc@gmail.com".gsub(/\A[\w+\-.]+/, "*")
```

Which gives output as

```rb
"*@gmail.com"
```

A possible solution to achieve what I want is to split the email address by @ and count the length of the first half of the string and replace with the same number of (*). But this is not an optimal solution and hence a regex to directly match and replace is expected.

**Expected Output**:

A regex which can match and replace characters before @ symbol leaving the first 2 characters as it is as below:

```rb
xy****@gmail.com
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `.gsub(/(?:\G(?!\A)|\A[^@]{2})\K[^@]/, '*')`

Comment: Or `.gsub(/(?<=[^@]{2})[^@](?=[^@]*@)/, '*')`

Comment: Hey @WiktorStribiżew, this works. Can you please post it below as an answer so that I can accept it. Also, a small brief on the regex will really help. Thanks again.

Comment: Email address consist of a *local part*, followed by the *at* character `'@'`, followed by the *domain part*. The [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) states that the local part of a valid email address may contain spaces and *special characters* that include `'@'`, provided they are quoted. `" "@example.org` is one example it gives of a valid email addresses. I therefore infer that `"@"@example.org` is also valid, though I've never seen an email address with more than one *at* character, and suspect that most issuers of email addresses would not provide them...

Comment: ...In any event, multiple *at* characters would play havoc with the solutions given. It may be a reasonable assumption to assume that valid email addresses contain exactly one *at* character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.gsub(/(?:\G(?!\A)|\A[^@]{2})\K[^@]/, '*')
```

Or,

```
s = s.gsub(/(?<=[^@]{2})[^@](?=[^@]*@)/, '*')
```

The regexps match

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\A[^@]{2})` - either the end of the previous successful match or start of string and any 2 chars other than a `@`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `[^@]` - a char other than `@`.

The second regex matches

- `(?<=[^@]{2})` - a location immediately preceded with any two chars other than a `@`
- `[^@]` - a char other than a `@`
- `(?=[^@]*@)` - a location immediately followed with any 0 or more chars other than a `@` and then a `@`.

Comment: I believe you made the reasonable assumption that email addresses contain exactly one `'@'` character (see my comments on the question). Accordingly, I believe your second regular expression can be simplified to `/(?<=.{2}).(?=.*@)/`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not go with:

```rb
a[0..1]+"*"*(a.index('@')-3)+a[a.index('@')..]
```

get the first two characters
`a[0..1]`

Convert all characters starting from the 3rd character up to(not including) the @ to a '*' 
`"*"*(a.index('@')-3)`

Get the rest of the string as is
`a[a.index('@')..]`

Comment: Hi @Vedant, thanks for the solution and it works too but I am looking for a regex which can do the same.

Comment: I think you want `"*"*(a.index('@')-2)`, but that's still a problem if `a = "x@y.com"`, in which case `"*"*(a.index('@')-2) #=> "*"*(1-2)`, which raises the exception `ArgumentError (negative argument)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /\A[^@]{3,}/
```

```
"xyz_abc@gmail.com".sub(r) { |s| s[0,2] + ('*' * (s.size-2)) }
  #=> "xy*****@gmail.com" 
"xy@gmail.com".sub(r) { |s| s[0,2] + ('*' * (s.size-2)) }
  #=> "xy@gmail.com" 
"x@gmail.com".sub(r) { |s| s[0,2] + ('*' * (s.size-2)) }
  #=> "x@gmail.com"
```